# Colors in errorbar and seaborn scatterplot not matching

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot

I am trying to add some x and y error on top of seaborn scatterplot. I am not able to find anywhere a solution to match the color between the two. I would be happy also with the marker being on top of the error lines and not the other way around.

Is there anyone who could help me?

Many thanks.

Here's the code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5), dpi=200)
sns.set_style("ticks")

sns.scatterplot(y="D47 CDES (Final)", x="D48 CDES (Final)", data=data, palette="muted", 
              hue="ID", style="ID", s=80)
plt.errorbar(y="D47 CDES (Final)", x="D48 CDES (Final)", xerr="D48 CDES (Final) CI", 
              yerr="D47 CDES (Final) CI", elinewidth=0.5,data=data, label=None, capsize=2, capthick=0.5)

plt.tick_params(axis='x')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', scatteryoffsets=[0.55], frameon=False, fontsize=9, ncol=3)
plt.xlabel("$\Delta_{48}$", fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel("$\Delta_{47}$", fontsize=15)

plt.xlim(0,0.5)
plt.ylim(0.45,0.7)
plt.savefig("a.jpg", bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

Here's the result:
[image: Plot]

Comment: What exactly is the advantage of using seaborn here? You have to modify the plot later on with matplotlib, so why not do it purely with matplotlib in the first place?

Comment: Well, I just find the hue and style mapping quite useful. And also I was not really looking to modify the plot, I just wanted to add one thing on top. But I am quite new at coding so I am really open to any suggestion about how making it better

Comment: If a function is not provided by seaborn/pandas, it is often more difficult to retrospectively change the graph than creating it according to your needs in the first place in matplotlib. It is not just "add one thing on top" - you have to retrieve the objects and modify their properties. This is often non-trivial. Maybe someone comes up with an easy way to pass parameters to seaborn - I would not know of a simple way to add this functionality.